# Text label automatically updates with temperature reading every one second

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created this code to read a temperature reading from a memory address using a MemoryReader.dll I found online, and then list the temperature reading in a label CurrentTemp.text.

The thermometer is constantly updating, so I'd like the label to update with that temperature. I would then like to be able to interrupt the for loop that is updating the temperature by clicking a button, to allow me to change other features on the menu (not yet implemented).

I couldn't figure out a way to have a start/stop button that edits a variable accessible from both the `button1_Click` method and `Stop_Click` method, so I have the `Stop_Click` method change the `Status.Text` label from on to off, which allows on off control.

Right now the code works except for the for loop.  When I add the for loop in, it causes the application to freeze when I click the Start button, and also the temperature value on the form does not update.

I searched thoroughly on stackoverflow and google, but I couldn't seem to find an answer that I could get to work.  Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MemoryEditor;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                if (Status.Text == "on")
                {
                    Memory oMemory = new Memory(); //Create Memory Class
                    if (oMemory.OpenProcess("D4IThermoMeter")) //Open Handle
                    {
                        double data1 = oMemory.ReadDouble(0x0049E054, new int[] { 0x8 });
                        CurrentTemp.Text = data1.ToString();
                    }

                }
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                this.Refresh();

            }
        }

        private void CurrentTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Status.Text == "on")
            {
                Status.Text = "off";
            }
            else if (Status.Text == "off")
            {
                Status.Text = "on";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  @AsadAli I was a bit rusty on how objects/classes/methods worked, so I took a few days to work on this.  I eventually managed to get a Timer to work, and it is initialized by a button click.  I also had problems with the Timer being able to access the Windows Form Object to change the text due to cross-thread access, and solved that by calling a delegate on the thread that runs the form.  I am now having problems enabling and disabling the timer.  I put a button controlled by the eventhandler Stop_Click, but it says "The name 'aTimer' does not exist in the current context"  Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MemoryEditor;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        public void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Memory oMemory = new Memory(); //Create Memory Class
            if (oMemory.OpenProcess("D4IThermoMeter")) //Open Handle
            {
                double data1 = oMemory.ReadDouble(0x0049E054, new int[] { 0x8 });
                this.SetText(data1.ToString());
            }
            //this.Refresh();
        }
        //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
        private void SetText(string text)
        {
            // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
            // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
            // If these threads are different, it returns true.
            if (this.CurrentTemp.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            else
            {
                this.CurrentTemp.Text = text;
            }
        }
        //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
        //public void ChangeText(string text)
        //{
        //    CurrentTemp.Text = text;
        //}
        private void CurrentTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Status.Text == "on")
            {
                Status.Text = "off";
                aTimer.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (Status.Text == "off")
            {
                Status.Text = "on";
                aTimer.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a timer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with LarsTech. Use a timer instead that has 1000 as interval and does the stuff (On the tick event) that your current for loop does.

```
private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Memory oMemory = new Memory(); //Create Memory Class
    if (oMemory.OpenProcess("D4IThermoMeter")) //Open Handle
    {
        double data1 = oMemory.ReadDouble(0x0049E054, new int[] { 0x8 });
        CurrentTemp.Text = data1.ToString();
    }
    this.Refresh();
}
```

As you noticed, i removed the if statement: That's because on the Stop button, you should also add a statement to enable/disable the timer.

```
public void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Status.Text == "on")
    {
        Status.Text = "off";
        MyTimer.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (Status.Text == "off")
    {
        Status.Text = "on";
        MyTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The `MyTimer` variable above is a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. If you want to use `System.Timers.Timer`, then see the approach below:

```
System.Timers.Timer MyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
void UpdateMyTimer() //A one-time call to this function must be made.
{
    MyTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
    MyTimer.Interval = 1000;
    MyTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

If `button1`'s purpose is to start the timer, then just paste the code above in the body of `button1_Click`.

Comment: This approach seems to work best, but I still have a problem with being able to access the Timer object I create on the first button press, please see edit.

Comment: That's because the variable `aTimer` is of local scope and it gets disposed as soon as the `button1_Click()` function ends its job. Add a Timer through the ToolBox (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) and use its `Tick` event ([Difference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

UI interaction like `Click` event runs on UI thread. So the `for` loop which execute on `Button_click` should block the UI thread to update the UI concurrently. There are couple of ways to update the UI in background. You can use `Timer` control which is an expensive one. Below is a simple way to upate the UI using `Delegate`

```
public delegate void DoAsync();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoAsync async = new DoAsync(GetThermoDetails);
    async.BeginInvoke(null, null);
}

public void GetThermoDetails()
{
    while (true)
    {
       //your code comes here
    }
}
```